# Haskell Create a UUID from String or Text

Tags: haskell

In Java (and other variants) I can create a UUID from a string like so

```
import java.util.UUID

val uuid = UUID.fromString("3ec3a7c7-0563-4de5-8424-c2aedd5aaf32")
```

If the UUID is not valid then this will throw an exception.  Checking out the Haskell UUID library I don't see an equivalent function (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-1.3.13/docs/Data-UUID-Util.html).  Is there a way to do this in Haskell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `fromString :: String -> Maybe UUID` in `Data.UUID`.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-1.3.13/docs/Data-UUID.html

Here in Haskell you won't get an exception but an output of type `Maybe` indicating success or failure.

Comment: In Haskell it is good to note the instances for the type of interest.  In this case you can see `UUID` is an instance of the `Read` type class so you can use `read` and get a value or exception, or use `Text.Read.readMaybe` to get the Maybe result.